# DWT: What is it and when and where we use it

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was reading up on the DWT for the first time and the document stated that it is used to represent time-frequency data of a signal which other transforms do not provide.

But when I look for a usage example of the DWT in MATLAB I see the following code:

```
X=imread('cameraman.tif');
X=im2double(X);

[F1,F2]= wfilters('db1', 'd');
[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(X,'db1','d');
```

I am unable to understand the implementation of `dwt2` or rather what is it and when and where we use it.  What actually does `dwt2` return and what does the above code do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two statements simply read in the image, and convert it so that the dynamic range of each channel is between `[0,1]` through `im2double`.

Now, the third statement, [`wfilters`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wfilters.html) constructs the wavelet filter banks for you.  These filter banks are what are used in the DWT.  The method of the DWT is the same, but you can use different kinds of filters to achieve specific results.

Basically, with `wfilters`, you get to choose what kind of filter you want (in your case, you chose `db1`: Daubechies), and you can optionally specify the `type` of filter that you want.  Different filters provide different results and have different characteristics.  There are a lot of different wavelet filter banks you could use and I'm not quite the expert as to the advantages and disadvantages for each filter bank that exists.  Traditionally, Daubechies-type filters are used so stick with those if you don't know which ones to use.

Not specifying the type will output both the **decomposition** and the **reconstruction** filters.  Decomposition is the forward transformation where you are given the original image / 2D data and want to transform it using the DWT.  Reconstruction is the reverse transformation where you are given the transform data and want to **recreate** the original data.

The fourth statement, `dwt2`, computes the 2D DWT for you, but we will get into that later.

---

You specified the flag `d`, so you want only the decomposition filters.  You can use `wfilters` as input into the 2D DWT if you wish, as this will specify the low-pass and high-pass filters that you want to use when decomposing your image.  You don't have to do it like this.  You can simply specify what filter you want to use, which is how you're calling the function in your code.  In other words, you can do this:

```
[F1,F2]= wfilters('db1', 'd');
[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(X,F1,F2);
```

... or you can just do this:

```
[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(X,'db1','d');
```

The above statements are the same thing.  Note that there is a `'d'` flag on the `dwt2` function because you want the forward transform as well.

---

Now, [`dwt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dwt2.html) is the 2D DWT (Discrete Wavelet Transform).  I won't go into the DWT in detail here because this isn't the place to talk about it, but I would definitely [check out this link](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/WaveletSoftware/standard2D.html) for better details.  They also have fully working MATLAB code and their own implementation of the 2D DWT so you can fully understand what exactly the DWT is and how it's computed.

However, the basics behind the 2D DWT is that it is known as a **multi-resolution** transform.  It analyzes your signal and decomposes your signal into multiple scales / sizes and features.  Each scale / size has a bunch of features that describe something about the signal that was not seen in the other scales.

One thing about the DWT is that it naturally subsamples your image by a factor of 2 (i.e. halves each dimension) after the analysis is done - hence the multi-resolution bit I was talking about.  For MATLAB, `dwt2` outputs four different variables, and these correspond to the variable names of the output of `dwt2`:

- `LL` - Low-Low.  This means that the vertical direction of your 2D image / signal is low-pass filtered as well as the horizontal direction.
- `LH` - Low-High. This means that the vertical direction of your 2D image / signal is low-pass filtered while the horizontal direction is high-pass filtered.
- `HL` - High-Low. This means that the vertical direction of your 2D image / signal is high-pass filtered while the horizontal direction is low-pass filtered.
- `HH` - High-High. This means that the vertical direction of your 2D image / signal is high-pass filtered as well as the horizontal direction.

---

Roughly speaking, `LL` corresponds to just the structural / predominant information of your image while `HH` corresponds to the edges of your image.  The `LH` and `HL` components I'm not too familiar with, but they're used in feature analysis sometimes.  If you want to do a further decomposition, you would apply the DWT again on the `LL` only.  However, depending on your analysis, the other components are used.... it just depends on what you want to use it for!  `dwt2` only performs a single-level DWT decomposition, so if you want to use this again for the next level, you would call `dwt2` on the `LL` component.

## Applications

Now, for your specific question of applications.  The DWT for images is mostly used in image compression and image analysis.  One application of the 2D DWT is in JPEG 2000.  The core of the algorithm is that they break down the image into the DWT components, then construct trees of the coefficients generated by the DWT to determine which components can be omitted before you save the image.  This way, you eliminate extraneous information, but there is also a great benefit that the DWT is **lossless**.  I don't know which filter(s) is/are being used in JPEG 2000, but I know for certain that the standard is lossless.  This means that you will be able to reconstruct the original data back without any artifacts or quantization errors.  JPEG 2000 also has a lossy option, where you can reduce the file size even more by eliminating more of the DWT coefficients in such a way that is imperceptible to the average use.

Another application is in watermarking images.  You can embed information in the wavelet coefficients so that it prevents people from trying to steal your images without acknowledgement.  The DWT is also heavily used in medical image analysis and compression as the images generated in this domain are quite high resolution and quite large.  It would be extremely useful if you could represent the images in the same way but occupying less physical space in comparison to the standard image compression algorithms (that are also lossy if you want high compression ratios) that exist.

One more application I can think of would be the dynamic delivery of video content over networks.  Depending on what your connection speed is or the resolution of your screen, you get a lower or higher quality video.  If you specifically use the `LL` component of each frame, you would stream / use a particular version of the `LL` component depending on what device / connection you have.  So if you had a bad connection or if your screen has a low resolution, you would most likely show the video with the smallest size.  You would then keep increasing the resolution depending on the connection speed and/or the size of your screen.

---

This is just a taste as to what the DWT is used for (personally, I don't use it because the DWT is used in domains that I don't personally have any experience in), but there are a lot more applications that are quite useful where the DWT is used.